# Accessing json does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using Ajax to receive a JSON update:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray());

        $.ajax ({
            url: '{{ path('PUSChatBundle_add') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(){
                $.get('{{ path('PUSChatBundle_refresh') }}', function(data){
                    alert(data[1].text);
                });
            }
        });
    });          

});
```

Now comes the bad the receiving JSON-Object looks like this:

```
[{"messageId":43,"text":"ghstgh"}]
```

and when I now want to access the text with:

```
alert(data[1].text);
```

I get undefined....

What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards,
Bodo

Comment: The first element of an array has index 0 - not 1.

Comment: Rather than using `alert` use the Javascript console that comes with just about any modern browser and use `console.log(data);` you can then inspect the variable and see exactly what is being returned in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `dataType` to `json` so that the response is parsed

```
success: function(){
                $.get('{{ path('PUSChatBundle_refresh') }}', function(data){
                    alert(data[0].text);
                },'json'); //<-- specify the dataType
            }
```

or manually parse the json

```
success: function(){
                $.get('{{ path('PUSChatBundle_refresh') }}', function(data){
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data); //<- parse json
                    alert(json[0].text);
                });
            }
```

example:

```
var j='[{"messageId":43,"text":"ghstgh"}]';
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
console.log(json[0].text); // or alert(json[0].text);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/X8GLL/1/)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript arrays start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your array only has one element, so you want to use `0` as your index:

```
alert(data[0].text);
```

Comment: @user1246987 you will have to parse the json response or set the `dataType` to `json`